# PHP insert data to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am experimenting with PHP and Mysql. I have created a database and table at mu localhost using xampp. I have also created a file that suppose to populate my table by executing a query, but the strange thing is that i get no errors but at the same time no DATA has been inserted into my DataBase:

CODE:

register.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){

    include('connectDB.php');

    $UserN = $_POST['username'];
    $Upass = $_POST['password'];
    $Ufn = $_POST['first_name'];
    $Uln = $_POST['last_name'];
    $Uemail = $_POST['email'];

    $NewAccountQuery = "INSERT INTO users (user_id,username, password, first_name, last_name, emial) VALUES ('$UserN','$Upass', '$Ufn', '$Uln', '$Uemail')";

    if(!mysql_query($NewAccountQuery)){

        die(mysql_error());

    }//end of nested if statment


    $newrecord = "1 record added to the database";

}//end of if statment

?>



<html>
<head>

<title>Home Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <header><h1>E-Shop</h1></header>


        <article>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>

            <h1>Create Account</h1>

        <div id="login">

                <ul id="login">

                <form method="post" action="register.php"  >
                    <fieldset>  
                        <legend>Fill in the form</legend>

                        <label>Select Username : <input type="text" name="username" /></label>
                        <label>Password : <input type="password" name="password" /></label>
                        <label>Enter First Name : <input type="text" name="first_name" /></label>
                        <label>Enter Last Name : <input type="text" name="last_name" /></label>
                        <label>Enter E-mail Address: <input type="text" name="email" /></label>
                    </fieldset>
                        <br />

                        <input type="submit" submit="submit" value="Create Account" class="button">

                </form>




                </div>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <div id="login">
                <ul id="login">
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="index.php" class="button"> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>      



        </article>
<aside>
</aside>

<div id="footer">This is my site i Made coppyrights 2013 Tomazi</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have also one include file which is connectDB:

```
 <?php


    session_start();

        $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
        if(!$con)
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db("eshop", $con) or die("Cannot select DB");

?>
```

Database structure:

database Name: eshop;
only one table in DB : users;

users table consists of:

```
user_id: A_I , PK
username
password
first_name
last_name
email
```

I spend a substantial amount of time to work this out did research and looked at some tutorials but with no luck

Can anyone spot what is the root of my problem...?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors?  Your `INSERT` statement specifies more columns than it has values.

Comment: I bet you have errors turned off.

Comment: are you entering same value for new entry? Try different value because user_id is PK

Comment: yes no errors and ye I removed user_id in a process I relised it is A_I. @Quentin i know this isynt a secure solution but its a dummy website and i just wont to get things working before i actually improve the code

Comment: add error_reporting(E_ALL); at top

Comment: @Tomazi — So. Step 1. Build it. Step 2. Throw it away. Step 3 . Build it again with the right tools? I strongly suggest skipping steps 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){`

you dont have input field with name `submitted` give the submit button name to `submitted`

`<input name="submitted" type="submit" submit="submit" value="Create Account" class="button">`

Check your insert query you have more fields than your values

Change  :

`$NewAccountQuery = "INSERT INTO users (user_id,username, password, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('$UserN','$Upass', '$Ufn', '$Uln', '$Uemail')";`

to :

`$NewAccountQuery = "INSERT INTO users (user_id,username, password, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('','$UserN','$Upass', '$Ufn', '$Uln', '$Uemail')";`

Considering `user_id` is auto increment field.

Your `email` in query is written wrongly as `emial`.

Comment: try echoing something inside if condition

Comment: OK u just sorted me out many thx. after amending the changes you suggested i also had an error: "Ok you got me going, but now i get an error which is "Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\eshop\connectDB.php on line 4"" so i also hadd to remove the session_start() fromy my register.php file

Comment: There are two `session_start()` remove one, Also dont forget to accept the answer :P

Comment: yes i did that once again thx :) of course I will you earned it. you can like my question in return if u wish :P

Answer (score 0):

Is error reporting turned on?
Put this on the top of your screen:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: this is not answer. this can be told in comments also

Comment: I have no add comment button under the question.

Comment: there is "add/show more comments" click it you will get comment box

Comment: I only have 'add comment' button under my answer.

Comment: It is written under users question!

Comment: ok, i got it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33419/cant-add-small-comments-to-questions

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers above, but I would also suggest you make use of newer MySQLi / PDO instead of outdated 2002 MySQL API.

Some examples: (i will use mysqli since you wrote your original example in procedural code)

connectDB.php

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     die(mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

register.php -- i'll just write out an example php part and let you do the rest

```
<?php
//i'll always check if session was already started, if it was then 
//there is no need to start it again
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

//no need to include again if it was already included before
include_once('connectDB.php'); 

//get all posted values
$username = $_POST['username'];
$userpass = $_POST['password'];
$usermail = $_POST['usermail'];
//and some more

//run checks here for if fields are empty etc?
//example check if username was empty
if($username == NULL) {
  echo 'No username entered, try <a href="register.php">again</a>';
  mysqli_close($db);
  exit();
} else {
  //if username field is filled we will insert values into $db
  //build query
  $sql_query_string = "INSERT INTO _tablename_(username,userpassword,useremail) VALUES('$username','$userpass','$usermail')";
  if(mysqli_query($db,$sql_query_string)) {
    echo 'Record was entered into DB successfully';
    mysqli_close($db);
  } else {
    echo 'Ooops - something went wrong.';
    mysqli_close($db);
  }
}
?>
```

this should work quite nicely and all you need to add is your proper posted values and build the form to post it, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     die(mysqli_connect_error());
?>
register.php -- i'll just write out an example php part and let you do the rest

<?php
//i'll always check if session was already started, if it was then 
//there is no need to start it again
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

//no need to include again if it was already included before
include_once('connectDB.php'); 

//get all posted values
$username = $_POST['username'];
$userpass = $_POST['password'];
$usermail = $_POST['usermail'];
//and some more

//run checks here for if fields are empty etc?
//example check if username was empty
if($username == NULL) {
  echo 'No username entered, try <a href="register.php">again</a>';
  mysqli_close($db);
  exit();
} else {
  //if username field is filled we will insert values into $db
  //build query
  $sql_query_string = "INSERT INTO _tablename_(username,userpassword,useremail) VALUES('$username','$userpass','$usermail')";
  if(mysqli_query($db,$sql_query_string)) {
    echo 'Record was entered into DB successfully';
    mysqli_close($db);`enter code here`
  } else {
    echo 'Ooops - something went wrong.';
    mysqli_close($db);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It might be a good idea to explain the ideas you have used here in some sort of summary or conclusion rather than comments, so you can expand on them in a more user friendly fashion.